# Really confused about how to load a .txt file into two arrays

Tags: java

I have a .txt file called capitals in my netbeans project folder which I need to create two parallel arrays for. The file contains 100 total entries, a state name on one line followed by a capital name of the next line. 50 states, 50 capitals.

I have googled and looked at examples on this site which contain the BufferedReader class but I am just not understanding the code provided to import the text file into 2 arrays and then call on them to be used in the program.

If somebody can help me with very simple explanations of code to use it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "Capitals.txt";

        int n = 50;
        String[] capital = new String[n];
        String[] state   = new String[n];

        try (Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName))) {

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                capital[i] = inputStream.nextLine();
                state[i]   = inputStream.nextLine();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        // do something with your arrays here
        // ...
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(capital));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(state));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man. One thing, can you show me how to do this: I would like the program to output each state one by one, followed by the user guessing the capital, and at the end it would show you how many were correct such as 33/50

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at  [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)  
Here's a nice tutorial on [how to read a file in Java.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)  
Here are some helpfull Stackoverflow links

[Parse data from text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730557/parse-data-from-text-file-in-java)

[Java - Parsing Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819772/java-parsing-text-file)